# NSManagedObject subclass outside of managed object as a normal object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, initialization

I have an entity object Country with country name and country code. It is a subclass of NSManagedObject and I am using it with core data model to store its value to a persistent store.

I have a place where the same Country object will used as a normal object i.e. I will use it to store some temporary country name.

For that I have initialized the Country as following

```
[NSManagedObject alloc] init]
```

Initialization successfully done, but I am not able to set any property to that object.
Hence I did an exploration. In that I found that, init for the NSManagedObject is not supported as per the documentation.

I don't know how to use the NSManagedObject Country with CoreData as well as a normal Object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2nd paragraph of the NSManagedObject class documentation's overview:

> A managed object is associated with an
>   entity description (an instance of
>   NSEntityDescription) that provides
>   metadata about the object (including
>   the name of the entity that the object
>   represents and the names of its
>   attributes and relationships) and with
>   a managed object context that tracks
>   changes to the object graph. It is
>   important that a managed object is
>   properly configured for use with Core
>   Data. **If you instantiate a managed
>   object directly, you must call the
>   designated initializer
>   (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:).**

From the documentation of the method:

> **Important**:  This method is the
>   designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You should not
>   initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.

The documentation is actually very good.

You do not want to try to use an NSManagedObject outside of a viable CoreData stack.   NSManagedObjects are quite explicitly designed to work within a correctly configured Core Data environment.   If you need a temporary instance, you can either create an in-memory store or create one in your regular store and just don't save the changes without deleting it first.

Comment: Thanks!! So it is not possible to initialize as we do for a normal object.

I suppose you are referring to NSInMemoryStoreType for the persistent store, so the inserted entity will be stored in volatile RAM memory. 

I have another question - when actually it will be cleared off or do we have to flush it out manually?

Comment: It'll be cleared when you tell it to clear (manually) or when your app quits... InMemoryStores work just like the other stores, just that persistence is... in memory only.

Answer (score 2):

Use `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` and pass `nil` for *managed object context*.